# How to display the number that is most repeated in the array?

Tags: javascript

I didn't find the simple example with JavaScript;

So I have an array with numbers and I need to show the number which is most repeated in array.

```
const getNumber = arr => {}

console.log(getNumber([1,2,5,2,8,5,2,10,1]))
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Could you please add the code?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i got this task on Interview, but I don't know how to make it right))

Comment: Look at my answer @Gover123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [4,5,4,3,2,1,7,8,4];

const sortArr = (arr) => {
  arr.sort();
    var max=0,result,freq = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]===arr[i+1]){
            freq++;
        }
        else {
            freq=0;
        }
        if(freq>max){
            result = arr[i];
            max = freq;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(sortArr(arr));   //Output 4
```

Comment: Can you explain me this part:         if(freq>max){
            result = arr[i];
            max = freq;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get an object with properties for all used numbers and their counts. Than use [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get out of this an array with the numbers and their counts and again use reduce to finde the number with the max-count. Get the number (first element) and return it.

```js
const getNumber = arr => {
    let counts = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!acc[cur]) {
            acc[cur] = 1;
        } else {
            acc[cur]++;
        }
        return acc;
    },{});
    return Object.entries(counts).reduce(([nr,max], [n, count]) => (count>max) ? [n, count] : [nr, max] )[0];

}

console.log(getNumber([1,2,5,2,8,5,2,10,1]));
```